# Why does the browser show the 404 view instead of loading a stylesheet in this Codeigniter 3 app?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a CMS with **CodeIgniter 3.1.8** and Bootstrap 4. I have decided to add themes to it. The application is **not HMVC**, only MVC.

The *themes* directory is outside *application* as can be see in the image below:

[image]

Inside *themes* I have the theme directory (of course) which contains the "master view", `layout.php`:

[image]

#### How I use the theme views

In `application/core` I have added a `MY_Loader.php` file with the following contents:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    function theme_view($folder, $view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
      $this->_ci_view_paths = array_merge($this->_ci_view_paths, array(FCPATH . $folder . '/' => TRUE));
      return $this->_ci_load(array(
              '_ci_view' => $view,
              '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars),
              '_ci_return' => $return
          ));
    }

}
```

In my Posts controller's `index()` method, I load the view passing it the data:

```
public function index() {
   //more code here
   $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);
    $this->load->theme_view('/themes/caminar/', 'layout', $data);
}
```

#### The problem

In `layout.php` I have included the theme's stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url('themes/caminar/assets/css/main.css')?>">
```

The file `main.css` is indeed at `http://example.com/themes/caminar/assets/css/main.css` yet, the browser, insted of loading the CSS file, loads the 404 view.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no directory `caminar` in the `themes` folder, from your screenshot.

Comment: What is shown in the source for the page where that href is?

Comment: @Dave `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ciblob.com/index.php/themes/caminar/assets/css/main.css">`

Comment: Notice the `index.php` in that URL? That would appear to be the source of your problem. You probably don't want/need the `site_url` in your href call. It's likely that simply echoing `/themes/caminar/assets/css/main.css` will work as you desire.

Comment: @Dave I did notice it and I don't think it is  the source of your problem, for the reasons I have mentioned.

Comment: Unless you are doing some rewriting or have a directory named `index.php` I don't see how a URL in that format would ever work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using site_url instead of base_url while loading your assets.

Site url is for links on your application, normally controller functions.

base_url is used for assets.

So change your paths to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('themes/caminar/assets/css/main.css')?>">
```

If that doesn't solve the problem then you might have something in your server preventing that. In that case show us your .htaccess if you're using apache Or your config for said virtual host if you're using nginx.

If its apache you can try and add this to your .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|themes|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
```

Comment: This is a progress, because it got 'index.php' out of the url, but it still does not load the stylesheet.

Comment: then show us your server configuration on that host. Because now that is not a codeigniter problem.

Comment: It is a XAMPP server.

Comment: I added `themes` to .htaccess and it works: `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|themes|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)`. Thanks for the help.